# Anyone having clipboard issues with VSTO and Windows 11 update KB5031354?

Tags: windows, vb.net, vsto, clipboard, office-addins

Since the update, any attempt to access the clipboard directly after use by an Office program triggers the error 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.' Before the update, this was not the case and uninstalling the update fixes the issue.

I'd be interested to know if anyone else is experiencing problems when accessing the clipboard since update KB5031354 (or the preview update KB5030310).

Tested in PowerPoint with a text selection (the last line crashes):

```
Dim vApp As PowerPoint.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
vApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy()
Dim vText As String = DirectCast(Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject(), Windows.DataObject).GetText()
```

And also in Excel:

```
Dim vRange As Range = vApp.Selection
vRange.Copy()
Dim vText As String = DirectCast(System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject(), System.Windows.DataObject).GetText()
```

Comment: Do you get the same issue with a standalone application, for example, when running a windows forms app?

Comment: I've managed to resolve this by uninstalling Office 2019, applying the Windows update and then reinstalling Office.

So I can't say whether the problem would show up in Windows Forms - just glad it's back working again!